# Grep the data only (-o) and the first column

Tags: text-processing, grep, csv

Sample data

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat data.csv 
A,4.4.4.4,4.4.4.5,4.4.4.6,3.3.3.3,3.3.3.4
B,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2,1.1.1.3,3.3.3.3
C,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1
D,2.2.2.1,2.2.2.1,2.2.2.2,2.2.2.3,2.2.2.4
wolf@linux:~$
```

There are a few duplicate data in this sample. e.g. there are two `3.3.3.3` which located in row A and row B.

```
wolf@linux:~$ egrep 3.3.3.3 data.csv 
A,4.4.4.4,4.4.4.5,4.4.4.6,3.3.3.3,3.3.3.4
B,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2,1.1.1.3,3.3.3.3
wolf@linux:~$
```

Right now I'm only interested with the 1st column which are `A,B,C,D` and also the related data.

Here is 4 data that I need to find.

```
2.2.2.3
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

So, I use `|` and `-o` in egrep

```
wolf@linux:~$ egrep '2.2.2.3|3.3.3.3|4.4.4.4|5.5.5.5' data.csv
A,4.4.4.4,4.4.4.5,4.4.4.6,3.3.3.3,3.3.3.4
B,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2,1.1.1.3,3.3.3.3
D,2.2.2.1,2.2.2.1,2.2.2.2,2.2.2.3,2.2.2.4
wolf@linux:~$
```

The output is good, but there is too much data in it. I just want the related data and the 1st column.

So, here is another attempt with `-o`

```
wolf@linux:~$ egrep -o '2.2.2.3|3.3.3.3|4.4.4.4|5.5.5.5' data.csv
4.4.4.4
3.3.3.3
3,3.3.3
2.2.2.3
wolf@linux:~$
```

The problem now I can't get the 1st column (`A/B/C/D`) with this

Next attempt

```
wolf@linux:~$ egrep '2.2.2.3|3.3.3.3|4.4.4.4|5.5.5.5' data.csv | cut -d , -f 1
A
B
D
wolf@linux:~$
```

I get the 1st column, but not the data. By looking at the output, I've no idea `A` represents both `3.3.3.3` and `4.4.4.4` as it's not being displayed on the output.

That's not really the output that I wanted. What I have in mind right now is something like this

**Desired Output**

Input

```
2.2.2.3
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

Output

```
D       2.2.2.3   
A,B     3.3.3.3
A       4.4.4.4
-       5.5.5.5
```

Unfortunately, I just can't think the solution for now. Please help

Answer (score 5):

```c
$ cat script.awk
NR == FNR {
  a[$0]
  next
}

{
  for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
    for (k in a) {
      if ($i == k) {
        a[k] = a[k] ? a[k] "," $1 : $1
      }
    }
  }
}

END {
  for (k in a) {
    print a[k] "\t" k
  }
}
```

Run it as:

```bsh
$ cat search.txt
2.2.2.3
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5

$ awk -F, -f script.awk search.txt data.csv
A,B     3.3.3.3
D       2.2.2.3
A       4.4.4.4
        5.5.5.5
```

Answer (score 4):

First note that the `2.2.2.3` regexp will match `2.2.2.3` but also `212.243` (as `.` is the regexp operator that matches any character) and also inside `22.2.2.36`.

Here, I'd use `perl`:

```
<data.csv perl -F, -lane '
  BEGIN {for (@l = qw{2.2.2.3 3.3.3.3 4.4.4.4 5.5.5.5}) {$v{$_} = []}}
  for (grep $v{$_}, @F[1..$#F]) {push @{$v{$_}}, $F[0]}
  END {for (@l) {print(join(",", @{$v{$_}}) || "-", "\t$_")}}'
```

Which gives:

```
D       2.2.2.3
A,B     3.3.3.3
A       4.4.4.4
-       5.5.5.5
```

To answer the question in the subject, for `grep -o` (`-o` being a non-standard extension btw) to report more than one portion of the input line on the output line, you could use `pcregrep`:

```
<data.csv pcregrep -o1 -o2 --om-separator=$'\t' \
  '^([^,]*).*?,(2\.2\.2\.3|3\.3\.3\.3|4\.4\.4\.4|5\.5\.5\.5)(,|$)'
```

But that can only report one of the words per line. Here it gives:

```
A       4.4.4.4
B       3.3.3.3
D       2.2.2.3
```

With `grep -Po`, assuming a `grep` built with perl-like regexp support (which btw in most implementations uses PCRE for the perl-like regexp matching, so it's the same as `pcregrep -o`), you could do:

```
$ grep -Po '^[^,]*+(?=.*?(?1))|((?<![^,])(2\.2\.2\.3|3\.3\.3\.3|4\.4\.4\.4|5\.5\.5\.5)(?![^,]))' data.csv
A
4.4.4.4
3.3.3.3
B
3.3.3.3
D
2.2.2.3
```

Which is `first-field-provided-there-is-matching-data|matching-data`.

Here the `provided-there-is-matching-data` is implemented with a `(?=...)` positive look-ahead operator which means *provided what follows matches `...`*, here `(?1)`, the regexp stored in the first capture group, so the matching data following any number of characters (`.*?`).

For the matching data, we have the `(2\.2\.2\.3|3\.3\.3\.3|4\.4\.4\.4|5\.5\.5\.5)` with the `.`s escaped, but with some negative look-around operators (`(?<!...)` and `(?!...)`) that say: *provided what's before and after are **not** characters other than `,`* to make sure those match the content of the csv fields exactly.

Answer (score 2):

One easy method is as follows. The keys to look for are listed one key per line in the  file named keys.txt and put on the stdin of perl command whilst the data to be searched is placed as an argument.

```
$ < keys.txt \
perl -F, -lane '
  $.==1 && chomp(@keys = <STDIN>);
  $_ .= "$F[0]," for @h{
    grep { my $k = $_; grep(($_ eq $k), @F)} @keys;
  }}{$, = "\t";
  print((($h{$_} //= "-") =~ s/,$//r), $_) for @keys;
' data.csv
D   2.2.2.3
A,B 3.3.3.3
A   4.4.4.4
-   5.5.5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --c2t -N reshape -r "^[^1]$" -o item,value \
then filter '$value=~"(2\.2\.2\.3|3\.3\.3\.3|4\.4\.4\.4|5\.5\.5\.5)"' \
then cut -x -f item \
then nest --implode --values --across-records -f 1 --nested-fs "," \
then reorder -f value data.csv >output
```

you will have

```
4.4.4.4 A
3.3.3.3 A,B
2.2.2.3 D
```

And then using your filter list

```
$ cat list
8.8.8.8
2.2.2.3
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

you can run

```
mlr --tsv -N join --ul -j 1 -f list then unsparsify output
```

to have

```
4.4.4.4 A
3.3.3.3 A,B
2.2.2.3 D
8.8.8.8
5.5.5.5
```